# Lock game object to its own x-axis

Tags: game-engine

Just been messing about with the game engine. I have a side scrolling shooting thing but when my ship is hit by an enemy bullet it gets knocked along the y-axis and off its current x axis direction. Is there a way to lock it to its own x-axis, so if its hit it will remain on that same vector? Once it has been hit by a bullet I can no longer give or take damage or pick up my wee gems because they can no longer make contact! I have tried the constraint actuator but with no joy. Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using a rigid body or a dynamic object?

Comment: Hi, Sorry should have mentioned. I am using a dynamic object.

Comment: [would this work?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ndXSj.png)